IIS 10 Strict-Transport-Security header is doubled up only when going through ARR
Windows Server 2016 Datacenter with IIS 10. For my web application, I have Strict-Transport-Security enabled through the web.config file like so.
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
    <remove name="X-AspNet-Version" />
    <remove name="MicrosoftOfficeWebServer" />
    <remove name="MS-Author-Via" />
    <add name="Strict-Transport-Security" value="max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>

For web traffic using my domain name, this works fine. But we have a large partner who wishes to use their own domain name. No problem - I use ARR and URL Rewrite to map their domain name to a particular page on our site. ARR is required so that their domain name works with their SSL certificate. This also works fine, except for the headers. For some reason, the Strict-Transport-Security header comes out twice. Even when I use the rewritten URL directly, this does not happen; only with their domain name. I assume the issue is coming from ARR. What makes me think this is, as you can see from the code above, one of the headers I am removing is X-Powered-By, but it also was coming through with a value of ARR/3.0. But I cannot find where Strict-Transport-Security might be coming from or is defined. I've been searching for the past day and have found nothing on point. Any suggestions would be welcome!

The HSTS header is only set once. Apparently the second duplicate header was added by ARR. Maybe you can use a URL Rewrite rule to remove this duplicate header in the response.

@YurongDai this suggestion worked. Thank you!
